# R: How can I set the y axis in radians in a plot?

Tags: r, plot, trigonometry

I want to plot the arctan of the fractions of two vectors (x and y):

```
atan.add <- atan(x/y)

plot(atan.add)
# I get this:
```

[image: artan.plot]

However, is there a way in R to get the y axis numbers as fractions of pi, i.e. pi/2, pi/4, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `axes=FALSE` in the `plot()` function and then define your own axes using `axis()`. Something like:

```
x <- 1:100            
set.seed(121)    
y <- rnorm(5)                     #random data
atan.add <- atan(x/y)
plot(atan.add,axes=FALSE)         #note the "axes=FALSE"
axis(side=1)                      #plot x axis (side=1)
axis(side=2, at=c(-pi, -pi/2, -pi/4, 0 ,pi/4, pi/2, pi), labels=expression(-pi, -pi/2, -pi/4, 0, pi/4, pi/2, pi))   #"side=2" specifies "y" axis
```

For more information, look at [**Plot Annotation in R**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/title.html) or [**Axes and Text in R Plot**](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html).

[image]

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- 1:20
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(20)
atan.add <- atan(x/y)
breaks_pi <- pretty(range(atan.add/pi))

plot(atan.add, yaxt="none")
axis(2, at = breaks_pi * pi, labels = paste(breaks_pi, "\u03c0"))
```

[image: resulting plot]